# FileNotFoundError OTA update 188 -> 226

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Updating Ubuntu Touch from r188 to r226 in the system settings gives me the error after full download:

FileNotFoundError /var/.../blacklist...

What is the easiest way to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-system-image/+bug/1277589/comments/40
I plugged the phone into my Ubuntu laptop via USB and typed into the terminal:

```
$ adb shell

root@ubuntu-phablet:/# system-image-cli --dry-run
Upgrade path is 192:194:226

root@ubuntu-phablet:/# system-image-cli
```

Now I am on 226.